# removing img border

Tags: css

I have a problem with the img border.  I am using the following code for all my images, but the border is not going away.  Can someone tell me the correct way to remove the img border?

```
   <div class="mosaic-overlay">
   <img class="cover1"></div>

   .cover1  {width:300px;height:185px;
            float:left;background: url('/img/cover.jpg') 0px 0px; 
            border:0;}
```

Many thanks.

Erik

Comment: this might be a silly question, but why are you using an img tag with a background image instead of a source? If you used a div tag you wouldn't have the border issue is all

Comment: make sure you close the img tag with `/>`

Comment: @joakim: Closing the `img` tag is unnecessary (even forbidden) in HTML 4, and in fact can cause rendering issues in older browsers.  Only close `img` tags if you're writing XHTML...and frankly, you shouldn't be writing XHTML either -- it usually ends up as tag soup, because hardly anyone actually gets it right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the default "special" border that appears in some browsers when an `img` element has no `src` attribute, or a `src` attribute pointing to an image that does not exist.

For example, look at this in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/SdbNE/

A common workaround is to set the `src` to a [`blank.gif` file](http://www-cdr.stanford.edu/~petrie/blank.gif):

```
<img class="cover1" src="blank.gif" />
```

Or, just use a `div` instead?

```
<div class="cover1"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Set your `<img>` source to transparent.

```css
#img {
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRvF4WdZJSA4MkWJXClae4eCvSdk87c5Ok63fgxBxVyR6aHB2Ju_A) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA" />
```

Notice the img src is blank and has no border but CSS sets the `background: url()`

> transparent src: `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA`

Credit [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/)

Answer (score 5):

it's the border of alt text, try

```css
img {
  text-indent: -999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use that java script trick, I initialise all images sources with a blank image.

```
onload=
var myImagesList =
document.getElementById("element where the images are").getElementsByTagName("img");

for (i=1;i < myImagesList.length-1;i++)
{
myImagesList[i].src = ".../blank image";
}
```