# How can I remove the border around an image without a source?

Tags: html, css

I have an image, and I haven't defined the source yet. It has a border :/

eg: `<img src="" />`

If I give it a source, the border goes away (due to the css: `border:none`).

How can I remove the border around an image when it doesn't have a source?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't have a source"? That you have an empty `<img src="" />` ?

Comment: I don't think you can, best to just add in the src or not have the image tag, or set its width/height to 0 unless there is a src available. You could also use a transparent image as a placeholder.

Comment: Exactly! Now, how do I remove the border from it?

Comment: @Louis Works great! Post that as an answer, and I'll use it! Thanks :D

Comment: Done, but I think this is a dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497992/removing-img-border

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What I could suggest is in case not having a src="" remove it and you can

```
img {
    display: none;
}


img[src] {
   display: block;
 }
```

or if you know like the url contains some special word, like http you can do:

```
img[src*="http"] {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: No problem .. at least can be useful for others :D

Comment: Its kind of sad people with the selected answer to the question can't gift it to another answer when the user who asked isn't around to update the question..

Comment: Late Response: The first answer worked just fine. Setting the width/height to 0px allows the image to be "invisible".

Comment: Nice answer! I'm still able to click on the img, which is what I needed.

Comment: Just came across this problem. Small improvement: I think it's better to use `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none` in order to prevent layout shifts.

Answer (score 33):

An image with a data: URL src attribute

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==">
```

Depending on your browser support required you could also:

```
img[src=""] {
  content:url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");
}
```

See: http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest to use `text-indent: 100vw;`

```css
.logo {
  text-indent: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="" alt="my logo" />
```

Comment: @fentas It is simply move the text position with `text-indent` properties. You can see the difference if you change the `text-indent` value

Comment: @QMaster can you try opposite value `text-indent: -100vw;` ?

Comment: watch out for hacks like this as the browser will render all that space, better try with low numbers until u achieve your goal

Answer (score 8):

This is my solution, work even if the image has no [src] attribute (ex. lozad.js).
Space preserved using opacity.

```
// prevent borders around images without [src] value/attribute
img[src=""],
img:not([src]){
  opacity: 0;
}

img[src="*"]{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`visibility: hidden;` keeps the space of the image empty.
`display: none;` hide completely the image and there is no reserved space

Comment: It does work, but without visibility I can't click on the image anymore. For this purpose I'm using `opacity:0;` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could just hide it until you give it a src.

```
img {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 visibility: hidden;    
}​
```

Or give it 0 size

```
img {
 height: 0;
 width: 0;  
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

Use alt attribute :It specifies an alternate text for an image, if the image cannot be displayed. The alt attribute provides alternative information for an image if a user for some reason cannot view it.

If you u don't want to display any alternative text if the image is not loaded then **leave the alternative attribute   empty**

```css
img {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="kansdkans" alt=" " />
```

If you **don't want to display anything** if the image is not loaded then use the below given css code:

```
img {
    display: none;
}    
img[src] {
   display: block;
 }
```

Working Example:

```css
img {
    display: none;
}
img[src] {
   display: block;
 }
```

```html
<img src="adfcd.png" alt=""  height="100" width="100"/>  <!--nothing will be displayed because source is not found -->
<br>
<img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20171210/0a9/linux-logo-vector-5a2d217764a349.8093308915129071274122.jpg" alt=""  height="100" width="100"/>
<!--image will be displayed if the source is found-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```css
.logo {
  text-indent: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="" alt="my logo" />
```

---

**Another solution**

```css
.logo {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="" alt="my logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The src of your img tag can be 404 Err. In this case, you can use follow as:

```
div.menu_avatar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.menu_avatar img{
    width:52px;
    height:52px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the space and avoid jumpy UI you can also try this:

```
img {
    opacity: 0;
}
img[src] {
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this little snippet!

```css
img[src=""],
img:not([src]){
  opacity: 0;
}

img[src]{
  opacity: 1;
}
```