# Can't remove border from img inside of label

Tags: html, css

This code creates a (what looks like, roughly) 1px solid border that is grey around the img. I set the images border to none, but it doesn't remove the border.

Here's the code :

```html
<label>
  <img style="width:200px;height:200px">
</label>
```

Comment: How does your CSS look like for img and label?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441362/how-can-i-remove-the-border-around-an-image-without-a-source

Answer (score 3):

This is a side effect of your HTML being invalid. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

An `img` element must have a `src`. Specify what image you want to load and the border goes away.

```html
<label>
  <img  src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137685/isolated/lists/c078654c8b1501b4c9ee784a330210e5-logo-geometric-polygonal.png" style="width:200px;height:200px">
</label>
```

If you want a box of certain dimensions without loading an image: Use a `div` or a different element.

Answer (score 0):

your img tag syntax is wrong. You have:

```
<label>
   <img style="width:200px;height:200px;">
</label>
```

but it should be:

```
<label>
   <img src="myimage.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
</label>
```

then the border will disappear! if you just want a white square use:

```
<label>
   <div style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></div>
</label>
```

let me know if you need any more clarification!