# struggling to remove border or list style type with this inline css

Tags: html, css, list, border, inline

```
<ul style="position:absolute; top:60px; left:50px; margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type: none; width:30%; height:600px; background: #ECECEC; box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"></ul>
<ul style="position:absolute; top:60px; left:50px; margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type: none; width:30%; height:400px; background: transparent; list-style-type: none;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
  <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/247204/pexels-photo-247204.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat center; background-size: auto; height: 100%; width: 100%;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
</ul>
```

http://jsbin.com/bafeyej/edit?html,output

Hi, I have tried a few different styling techniques, border: 0; etc. and I can't seem to get rid of this little outline around the image, I know its from its parent elements however I can't seem to hack it, I even dared to set outline to none. I'm such a trouble maker, any ideas?

FYI, I am creating a profile template for an online platform, which only permits limited use of html code in the profile making section, so please no lectures why I shouldn't be using inline CSS or why I am using a ul element as a container lol, it is what it is.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: wow! what a very bad with no meaning code ... sorry but i have to say it

Comment: useful as a chocolate teapot Temani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your problem come from the fact that your img tag don't have a src attribute.

I found this post, on a similar issue, where you'll probably find a solution.

[How can I remove the border around an image without a source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441362/how-can-i-remove-the-border-around-an-image-without-a-source)

Comment: Thank you! Charles you are a legend!

Comment: Charles I need your help again if possible? http://jsbin.com/lizaquk/1/edit?html,output

I'm trying to get the columns to stay equal when collapsing, any ideas?

Comment: I'm flattered you think I can help, but I'm far from a specialist. Besides, I'm not sure to understand your question. You should post this as a new question, more people will see it.

Comment: ok, thank you for looking into it though it's very much appreciated!